# Where can I ask questions about the physics of fiction?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I looked at Worldbuilding, but that's only about fiction (not about real-life applications), and I don't see any questions on Physics about fiction.

Here are some examples:

- Is it really possible to shoot around corners, like lots of movies show?
- Are rocket jumps actually possible?
- Could a portalgun safely exist?

Is there even a site for this?

Comment: Can you please give some specific example questions, using actual things instead of the letters? It will be easier to understand.

Comment: Presumably, [physics.se] in fiction will match physics in the real world. Where it'll diverge will be in speculative fiction, so I'd expect [scifi.se] would be the right spot.

Comment: A lot of those questions sound like they would be fine for Worldbuilding.

Comment: @HDE226868 From their tour page, "Worldbuilding Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for writers, artists and others using science, geography and culture to construct imaginary worlds and settings." I'm looking for "Can this be done in real life?" But thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI The site has changed since that was written up. Look at some of our newer answers. Our top two tags, [tag:science-based] and [tag:reality-check], contain questions like yours. The motivation for asking a question doesn't have to be for actually creating a world - in fact, most of our questions are just asked out of curiosity.

Comment: @HDE226868 Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI You're welcome! At the risk of sounding like a salesperson, I invite you to browse around a bit there. There might be something that could answer one of your questions. I can't recall anything off the top of my head, but something could be there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The trick is distinguishing the **motivation** for the question from the actual question itself.

If your question is "In movie X, how/why did character A do F?" (i.e., you want an "in-universe" answer) then that's probably on-topic for [SciFi.SE](http://scifi.stackexchange.com) or [MoviesAndTV.SE](http://movies.stackexchange.com).

If your question is "I saw F in movie X. Is it actually possible to do F?" (i.e., you want a "real world" answer) then that's probably on-topic at whichever of [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com)/[Chemistry](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com)/[Biology](http://biology.stackexchange.com)/[etc.SE](https://stackexchange.com/sites#science-name) applies to F. As long as you make it very clear that movie X is not crucial to the question, and you aren't expecting answerers to be experts on movie X, it should be fine.

Comment: In any instance where the question is about a movie or TV show, even if the question is asking for a more indepth analysis on whether something is possible, it would be on topic on M&TV but you might get a better answer on a site specifically for the area of science you're after.